# Calligraphic E (not \mathcal)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

I write my notes in statistics with LaTeX. The lector uses a special E as the sample space and I can't find it in LaTeX. Are there any other calligraphic math font styles then `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`?

Here's what the symbol looks like handwritten:

[image: symbol image]

Comment: Have you tried detexify ( http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html )?  It works for fonts as well.  If that doesn't help, it would be useful to have an idea of the character you are trying to reproduce.  Could you sketch it and upload the picture?

Comment: Try `eucal` package and `mathrsfs` package. Theses are most common ones.

Comment: Well, there's also `\mathfrak`.

Comment: detexify does not know it... i think its a very uncommon symbol, besides that the lector also said that some symbols he used are very uncommon even in literature... (All his slides are hand written)

Comment: I wouldn't bother reproducing exactly the handwriting; `\mathscr{E}` seems like what the lecturer is trying to imitate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try doing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\begin{document}
  The sample space is $\mathpzc{E}$.
\end{document}
```

See [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive), page 68 for a pretty complete list of math fonts available and how to get to typeset them.

You can also check [A comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode), page 95 onwards.

There's also [The LaTeX Font Catalogue - Calligraphic and Handwritten Fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html).

Comment: i think this looks mostly like the handwritten one, thanks! i think i will just take this one, i will know what it is :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try rsfs: The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

The sample space is $\mathscr E$.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: no thats not the symbol.. i uploaded a picture from the slides. http://user.42.lefant.net/~reox/lfs.png

Comment: @reox You should edit your question to include that picture. Like this, more people will notice it and may be able to help.